# MVC Jquery $.each not returning data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application that will display names that are populated in a list. A timer will display beside the first name in the list until the time is up (in that case the name is deleted and the timer will display beside the next name).

I have  jQuery function below that is not returning the namesback to my table.  This line:

```
 window.alert("Userlist: " + JSON.stringify(usersList));
```

returns the data that is is usersList

[usersList data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCbqN.png) (see screenshot)

[image]

This line is not returning any data:

```
row = $('<tr id="row-' + item.id + '"><td>' + item.FullName + '</td></tr>');
```

thanks for any guidance

View.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<RangeTest.Models.UserNameModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "";
}
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="jumbotron">


<hr />

@*<button id="pauseButton">Pause</button><br />*@
<table class="table" id="NameList">
    <tr>

        <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> 
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FullName)
        </th>

        <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> 
            Time Remaining
        </th>
       <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>

            <td>@ViewBag.Message</td>

    </tr>


</table>

</div>
<br/>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

    var usersList = [];

    function init() {

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetNames", "UserNames")',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            async: true,

            success: function (data) {

                var row = null,
                    first = true,
                    timer = null;

                // populate local users list:



                usersList = data;
                window.alert("Userlist: " + JSON.stringify(usersList));
                // populate HTML for table:
                $.each(usersList, function () {
                    $.each(this, function (index, item) {
                        row = $('<tr id="row-' + item.Id + '"><td>' + item.FullName + '</td></tr>');
                        // row = $('<tr id="row-' + item.Id + '"><td>' + item.FullName + '</td></tr>');
                        window.alert("row: " + row);
                        // add a timer to the first row:
                        if (first) {
                            $(row).append(getTimer());
                            $(row).append("<td>" + "<button id='pauseButton'>Pause</button>" + "</td>");
                            first = false;
                        }

                        $('#NameList').append(row);
                    });
                });

            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
    init();


    function restartTimer() {

        var deletedElement = null,
            nextId = null,
            newRow = null,
            row = null,
            that = this;

        // remove the deleted item from local array:
        deletedElement = usersList.shift();
        window.alert("deletedElement: " + JSON.stringify(deletedElement));
        // delete record from db on server:
        $.ajax({

            url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "UserNames")',
            type: "POST",
            data: ({ id: deletedElement.Id }),
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,

            async: true,
            success: function (data) {

                // remove this timer:
                $(that).remove();
                $('#row-' + deletedElement.Id).remove();


                // add new record to local array: 
                usersList.push(data);



                nextId = usersList[0].Id;


                // add a timer to the new item:
                row = $('#row-' + nextId);


                row.append(getTimer());
                $(row).append("<td>" + "<button id='pauseButton'>Pause</button>" + "</td>");

            }

        });
    }



    function getTimer() {
        var timer = $('<td></td>');
        $(timer).countdown({
            layout: '{mnn} : {snn}', timeSeparator: ':', until: 10, onTick: TimerColorChange, onExpiry: restartTimer
        });


        $(document).on('click', '#pauseButton', (function () {
            var pause = $(this).text() === 'Pause';
            $(this).text(pause ? 'Resume' : 'Pause');
            $(timer).countdown(pause ? 'pause' : 'resume');
        }));
        return timer;
    }

    function TimerColorChange(periods) {

        var seconds = $.countdown.periodsToSeconds(periods);
        if (seconds <= 5) {
            $(this).css("color", "red");
        } else {
            $(this).css("color", "black");
        }

    }    
});

function refresh() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '',
        context: document.body,
        success: function (s, x) {
           // $(this).html(s);

        }
    });
}
    refresh();
setInterval(refresh, 20000);
```

Admin view that gets the name from the user to populate the list.

```
  @model IEnumerable<RangeTest.Models.UserNameModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "";
}
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="jumbotron">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Admin", "UserNames", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


        WebGrid dataGrid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: false, canSort: false);


    <div class="table-bordered">
        <div class="Title">Admin - Add names to list</div><br />
        <table id="TblAdd"class="table">

            <tr>

                @{
            RangeTest.Models.UserNameModel t = new RangeTest.Models.UserNameModel();
        }

                @Html.Partial("_AddDynTable", t)

</table>
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive">

            <div class="Title">Names Added to List</div>

                    <table class="table" id="tblNames">
                        <tbody>

                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @dataGrid.GetHtml(columns: dataGrid.Columns(
                                                               dataGrid.Column(format: @<text>@item.FullName</text>),
                                                               dataGrid.Column("", format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.id })))
                                                               )
                                    </td>


                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
}

                            </div>

                            <br/>
```

Controller:

```
    static List<UserNameModel> userList = new List<UserNameModel>();
    public ActionResult Admin()
    {


        return View(userList);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Admin(UserNameModel model)
    {


        var highestId = userList.Any() ? userList.Select(x => x.Id).Max() : 1;
        model.Id = highestId + 1;
        userList.Add(model);

        return View(userList);

    }





    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetNames()
    {

        return Json(userList.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


    }
```

Model:

```
 public class UserNameModel
 {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Name:")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }    

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`usersList` is the array with data. You just need to loop that and get items. No need of 2 loops.

```
$.each(usersList, function (index,item) {
  var row = $('<tr id="row-' + item.Id + '"><td>' + item.FullName + '</td></tr>');
  // add a timer to the first row:
  if (first) {
        $(row).append(getTimer());
        $(row).append("<td>" + "<button id='pauseButton'>Pause</button>" + "</td>");
        first = false;
  }
  $('#NameList').append(row);
});
```

**The problem with your current code** is, you are first looping through the array of items, and inside the loop, you are looping again. This time (in the inner loop), you are basically looping `this` which is basically the current item in your outer loop(from the array). So basically instead of passing an array to the second `$.each` loop, you are passing a javascript object with an `Id` and `Name` property. So inside the second `$.each` loop, the `item` variable will have each property value of our single js object(`this` of our previous loop iterator). That does not have any `Id` property or `Name` property. So your js code should crash with an error message like "Cannot read property Id"!

You can verify this by putting a `console.log` in your loop and open the browser console (press F12)

```
$.each(usersList,function () {
   console.log('this', this);

   $.each(this,function (index, item) {

      console.log('item in second loop',item);
      // There is no Name property on item 

   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's that second .each that's getting you.  Check out the [jQuery each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) page and you'll see that when iterating over an object (such as in your second call to the function), the first param in the callback is the property name and the second is the value of that property.  The way that you are trying to create your tr, you could simply accomplish by setting "this" in your first .each to a variable called item or going straight off of the "this" object.  See the fiddle below:

[Fiddle w/ solution](https://jsfiddle.net/tburki/zv06r375/)

```
var usersList = [
  {
    Id:2,
    FullName: 'Test Name'
  },
  {
    Id: 3,
    FullName: 'Test 2'
  }
];
$.each(usersList, function () {
  row = $('<tr id="row-' + this.Id + '"><td>' + this.FullName + '</td></tr>');
  window.alert("row: " + row[0].outerHTML);
  //...rest of code here
});
```